# Apache error 500 on large file uploads (mod_security)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, centos7, mod-security

As far as I've tried, none of the usual solutions works for me. Well, my problem, I'm receiving an 500 Error every time I upload a "large file" (600 KB ~), with smaller images it works fine. So..., even with this (extreme) .htaccess file it keeps happening, and yes, .htaccess are active:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
memory_limit = 128M
max_input_time = 6000
max_execution_time = 6000
```

So, I take a look at the logs and find this (is only one line, just pasted it as easy to read with line jumps):

```
[Mon Jul 27 17:09:28.<port> 2015] [:error] [pid 21423] [client <ip>]    
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 44 (phase 2). 
Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY" required. 
[file "/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf"] 
[line "35"] [id "<another id>"] 
[msg "Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary."] 
[hostname "<my host>"] [uri "<my script>"] [unique_id "<id (useless I think)"]
```

But, now I not able to find how to edit the mod_security (it has the default config, and empty activated_rules) config in order (i think) to allow this "large" file uploads. I'm running PHP 5.3 in Apache 2.4/CentOS 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fact you have a `ModSecurity alert` means that you can't have empty activated_rules folder or you are including the rules in some other way.

There are [known problems with ModSecurity for this error](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/652) and it seems very susceptible to false positives.

The main advice when I rule is raising too many false positives is to just turn off that rule (I'm assuming it's rule  200003 that's firing but replace the id as appropriate):

```
SecRuleRemoveById 200003
```

Comment: Added both rules (I applied 2 MB), but it keeps returning 500.

Comment: Did you restart Apache to pick up these changes? Was it rule id 960915 which was firing? Did you add the remove code to the config AFTER the config where rule 970915 was defined and not before?

Comment: Yes, I'm restarting apache everytime. Don't know where rule 960915 is being "stored" i just pasted the line at the end.

Comment: Ok but you removed the ID when you pasted it so not sure if it is 960915. You need to go through your Apache config and see how and when the rules are being loaded.

Comment: Ok, I found this line 
SecRule MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
    "id:'<the id>',phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:44,msg:'Multipart request body \
    failed strict validation,
and used your removeByID of that id, but it persists.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is an accepted answer for the OPs upload issue. Should it not be `SecRequestBodyLimit` that should be updated for an upload issue? The default is 12.5MB.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error:

> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 44 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY" required. [file "/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf"] [line "34"] [id "200003"] [msg "Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary."]

But @nilpo answer was correct
I got this issue due to the image name and after changing the name issue solved.

But it's not something I want because I know the solution but my customer did't know that they have to change the name.

Answer (score 0):

try to check FcgidBusyTimeout parameter in fcgi configuration

Comment: 3600, but the page return the error 500 in almost 700 ms.

Answer (score -1):

Rename the file you are attempting to upload.  This error indicates the file name contains a character that is disallowed by mod_security.  Rename the file and then try uploading it again.  By disabling the mentioned line in mod_security.conf, it will happily skip past this check but that leaves your server open to vulnerabilities.

Comment: This answer does not apply to this error message.  The filename is not at issue.

Answer (score -3):

all i am found SOLUTION!!!

UBUNTU 16.04 + Apache (MY mod_secure WORK AND UPLOAD OK)

**0. apache a2enmod headers** (activate headers and .htaccess)

**1. CHECK .htaccess !!!!!**

//in .htaccess

**php_value upload_max_filesize 50M**

**php_value post_max_size 50M**

//if you want custom in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

2. https://www.maketecheasier.com/securing-apache-ubuntu/ instruction for commands

sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.conf - **last 2 lines i am comment**

sudo nano /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf - **configuration mod_secure is easy**

sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf - **apache configuration CTRL+W**

//on/off

```
bash->a2dismod mod-security2 //off
```

*or*

```
bash->a2dismod security2 //off


bash->a2enmod mod-security2 //on
bash->a2enmod security2 //on
```

3. If you want you can remove specific rules:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/modsecurity/find-and-disable-specific-modsecurity-rules

SecRuleRemoveById 950004 in modsecurity.conf

4. Byteconverter - http://whatsabyte.com/P1/byteconverter.htm

THIS IS ENOUGHT!!!!

4 hour!!