# Modsecurity multipart boundary false positives

Tags: spring-boot, apache, spring-mvc

Some PDF file uploads are rejected by the ModSecurity rule:
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 44 (phase 2).
Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY" required.
(see [Apache error 500 on large file uploads (mod_security)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659316/apache-error-500-on-large-file-uploads-mod-security))
Is it safe to disable the rule if the applications behind the proxy are running on SpringBoot with SpringMVC?

Expecting all PDFs to be uploadable.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about two different issues: `MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY` occurs if a rule (usually `200004`) triggered, and the other one is the Apache's 500 error. The last one can be because of several different things, I can't tell you anything now.

But regarding for the first one: yes, I think you can remove that rule without any risk. There were many tries to solve this issue (I provided one for [libmodsecurity3](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/pull/1747) and one for [mod_security2](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/pull/2193)). The second one was rejected (see the discussion), but (even though I fixed this issue) I almost always turn off this rule, it's completely unnecessary.